# Question regarding certainty of certain assumptions in this triangle problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image: Problem]

In the following problem Khan claims that the upper angle is $\theta$ since the angle on the bottom right is $90°-\theta$ and it is a right triangle. However I don't see any proof that the striped line is perpendicular to the base of the pyramid to call it such.

Also he claims that the triangle in blue with side $h$ is also a right triangle by the black line hitting the top of the water. But I don't see any proof of this either.

He also claims the diagonal right side of the pyramid is $180-72$, but how can we know that the pyramid isn't asymmetric?

Am I right to say that in simple geometry problems such as these you just have to "assume" right triangles and symmetry without proof for simplicity sake? Maybe I am being stupid here.

Comment: They are right angles by construction: the solution to the problem should start with "Drop a perpendicular from the tip of the pyramid to its base...." etc.

Comment: @NickD yes but how can you prove what the length of the perpendicular line would be?

Comment: We know the structure of the pyramid - so symmetry is given. The measurements were done with "verticality" feature - it is not assumption. The problem asks you to use similarity to determine h.